# How do you determine if a geometric construction has degrees of freedom?

Tags: geometry

I would like to know if there is a common approach to proving or disproving whether degrees of freedom exist after following a geometric construction scheme? To clarify, that the result of the construction is similar and any differences can be explained by translation, rotation, scaling or reflection. An example is the construction and hypothesis below, also illustrated by a figure.

**Construction.**
A triangle is constructed such that one circle contains its circumcenter, its centroid, its incenter and one vertex. Another circle contains its orthocenter, its centroid, and its incenter, and it also has a tangent in one of the sides of the triangle.

**Hypothesis.**
All such constructed triangles are similar.

[image: Four Centers of Triangles]

If instead various methods are used, it would be interesting to list them.

Comment: what does degree of freedom means in this context?

Comment: Well, in the example I provided there are naturally an infinite number of triangles, but they would all be similar (if true). So, always leading to the same result, where sameness would be lax enough to allow translation, scaling, and reflection? Perhaps I am not using the right terminology, so if you have any suggestion for a reformulation I'd be happy to edit the question.